How find the Eigenvectors of a 2 by 2 matrix using MathNet.Numerics without implicit conversion error?
using System;
using System;
using MathNet.Numerics;
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double;
using System.Globalization;
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Factorization;
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra;
using System.Numerics;


Matrix<double> processedData11 = Matrix<double>.Build.Random(5, 5); 
Evd<double> eigen22 = processedData11.Evd();
MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Vector<Complex> eigenvector99 = eigen22.EigenVectors;


Error is indicated at: eigen22.Eigenvectors;
The error message (CS0029) says cannot implicitly convert from     MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Matrix to MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Vector<System.Nmerics.Complex>

I have tried using the potential fixes to no avail. Can someone provide some direction on this. An example would be nice. Thanks, James

Looks like eigen22.EigenValues will get you a Vector.  eigen22.EigenVectors will get you a Matrix.
